# GetFileByServerRelativeUrl is returning 400 bad request

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, error, file, file-download

I am trying to download file from SharePoint using below code

```
url ='https://site_url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/PraveenTest/Test/file_name")/$value'
headers = {Authorization: "Bearer"  + accessToken}
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

response is 400.

Why exactly I am facing this issue?

Comment: Can you please post the complete code you are using? Also, check the relative path you provided is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the complete example of how to get the file from SharePoint:

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getParameterByName('SPHostUrl'));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getParameterByName('SPAppWebUrl'));

var fileContentUrl = "_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/library/madcow.xlsx')/$value?@target='" + hostweburl + "'";

var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
var info = {
    url: fileContentUrl,
    method: "GET",
    binaryStringResponseBody: true,
    success: function (data) {
        //binary data available in data.body
        var result = data.body;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
};
executor.executeAsync(info);
```

**Source**: [How to copy files between sites using JavaScript REST in Office365 / SharePoint 2013](https://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html).

You can also check below documentation for Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints:

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints).

Comment: Hi, does this answers your question? If Yes, please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

There is also this method.

```
https://siteurl/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('List or Library Name/')/Files('File Name')/
```

The following example shows how to retrieve a file.

```
https://my365.onmicrosoft.com/sites/sample/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('SiteAssets/')/Files('01.jpg')/
```